# using merge statement with utl_file

Tags: sql, oracle, rdbms

Is there a way we could use the merge statement in the utl_file I didn't see example of it.
the merge statement I am using is:

```
MERGE INTO ford.product_image i
USING (SELECT  code  serv_part_no,              
             iname image_url,                 
             itype Itype           
             FROM ford.product_image )v    
 ON (L_ICODE = i.code)  
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
   UPDATE SET i.iname = l_iname
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
 INSERT (code,iname,itype)
 VALUES(l_icode, l_iname, l_itype);
```

L_ICODE is the variable the is coming from a utl_file

Comment: I assume utl_file is something obvious for people familiar with the DBMS you are using. Perhaps you should tag your question with that DBMS?

Comment: Get your data from utl_File into a temp table in sql server and then use that temp table in your merge statement.

Comment: Do we have to create a temp table is there any other way we could approch this  problem.

Comment: @Awais something has to know how to parse the file.  Are you pushing it through an app first?

Comment: @paqogomez no just the stored procedure in oracle

Comment: @Awais - Why don't you want to use a temporary table?  You could use a SQL collection as well.  Without knowing why you want to avoid using the temporary table, though, it's impossible to know whether the same objection would be present for the collection.

Comment: @JustinCave  since i am using the same source table . i dont think creating a temp table would help . i know it will be esay to match and insert but that might take time.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the comment.  What does "using the same source table" mean?  You mean that the source and the destination table are the same?  What is your `MERGE` statement trying to accomplish?  Does the file have a single value that you are reading in to `L_ICODE`?  Or does the file have many different values that you want to read?

Comment: my table have three column, and the file also contain three values  let say column a, b, c   what i am trying to achive here is if column a = a2  and c = c2 than  update b. if not than insert. a2 and c2  is is comming from a variable

Comment: if your file is a CSV, use oracle's external table and be done with it.

Comment: @Awais - It's usually best to upload to a temp table regardless (or something regarded by the system the same).  For one thing, it means you have an easier time doing some error-checking before uploading to/updating the main table.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i got the work arond for it .. if we use the dual table instead of source table to pass the variable in. its working fine now